# Formating output of this Python employee program I am building

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a basic Employee program to help me learn how Python works. Although, the program works the output I am trying to attain is not what I am looking for. Here is the code I have so far, it is rather long but fairly straight forward I believe:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.id = id
    self.pay = pay

  def info(self):
    if isinstance(self, Supervisor):
      return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.first, self.last, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
                   "\nEmployee's under supervision:", self.print_emp())
    elif isinstance(self, Developer):
      return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.first, self.last, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
                   "\nPrograming Language:", self.prog_laung)
    else:
      return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.first, self.last, "\nSalary:", self.pay)

class Supervisor(Employee):
  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)

  def print_emp(self):
    for emp in self.emp_under_sup:
      print(emp.first, emp.last)

class Developer(Employee):
  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, prog_laung):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    self.prog_laung = prog_laung

sup1 = Supervisor('Jake', 'Derber', 1, 70000)
sup1.info()
print()
dev1 = Developer('Rob', "M", 2, 60000, 'Python and Java')
sup1.add_emp(dev1)
sup1.info()
```

The output that the above code produces is as follows:

```
Employee ID: 1
Full name: Jake Derber 
Salary: 70000 
Employee's under supervision: None

Rob M
Employee ID: 1 
Full name: Jake Derber 
Salary: 70000 
Employee's under supervision: None
```

However, what I really want the output to be is different. The output I was attempting to generate would be:

```
Employee ID: 1 
Full name: Jake Derber 
Salary: 70000 
Employee's under supervision: None

Employee ID: 1 
Full name: Jake Derber 
Salary: 70000 
Employee's under supervision: Rob M
```

I have tried doing this a few different ways. I am sure I am not far off. If someone could explain to me why the output is not what I am expecting? I have tried running through a debugger but I am using a new IDE (PyCharm) and I can't figure out how to simultaneously display my output and my debugging information so it has been rather unhelpful.

Comment: `return print` returns `None`, while still executing the `print` statement.  This is also why the employees under supervision are getting printed in the wrong place.  You just need to be returning from these functions instead of printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `return print(...)` in Python, the call to `print` is executed, and the result of the call to `print` is returned.  However, `print` always returns `None`, so you are returning `None`.

You do this several times through your program.

The particular issue you reference in your output comes from the following line:

```
print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.first, self.last, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
               "\nEmployee's under supervision:", self.print_emp())
```

In this line, you are calling `self.print_emp()`, which is getting called, and the result of the function is printed with everything else.

The function `self.print_emp()` is ***executed*** first, and inside this function you print all of your employees.  This is why the employees are printed above the rest of the information.

The function then ***returns*** `None`, which is why `None` is printed in the final output.

Here is a minimal example of the behavior you are experiencing:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('Hello World')

>>> print('Testing: ', foo())
Hello World
Testing:  None
```

To fix this type of behavior, use `return` instead of `print`:

```
>>> def foo():
...    return 'Hello World'

>>> print('Testing: ', foo())
Testing:  Hello World
```

Or in your case, do something like:

```
def print_emp():
    return ', '.join([' '.join([emp.first, emp.last]) for emp in self.emp_under_sup])
```

Comment: Ah I see now, thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Should I reformat my info() method so that I am not returning print statements? Is that a normal Python convention would you say?

Comment: `return print` will print and then return `None`.  I would recommend returning the string and printing the result.